# IOS 5 IFrame with a PDF, Display and scroll issues

Tags: javascript, ios, pdf, iframe, jquery-mobile

I am running IOS 5.1.1 on an IPad One.  My application is a `HTML5` App and uses `JQuery Mobile`.  I have an `IFrame` that is programmatically inserted.  The `IFrame` has some criteria that is then used to generate a `PDF` inside the `IFrame`.

1. the `PDF` won't display unless the I-Pad is rotated.
2. I cannot scroll the `IFrame`

On I-Pad 2 (running 4.1.3) I have no problems it displays and (two finger) scrolls fine.

The code is as follows:

**JQM Page, Content Section**

```
        <div class="content overflowScroll" data-role="content">
        </div><!-- /content -->
```

**CSS**

```
.overflowScroll {
    height: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

**The IFrame Insert**

```
strHtml = '<iframe src="' + fullUrl + '" width="100%" height="95%" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></iframe>';
$page.find(".content").empty().html(strHtml);
```

**Update**

The problem looks to be IOS5 as the same thing happens on a mobile running IOS5.  Is there a good alternative here?  Perhaps If i remove dependancy from an iframe?

Comment: I got the same problem. We use a webview and set it[_webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];